# Header() function not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever verifyUser is returned true then the if statement should execute but for some reason instead of going to the header location, the page just refreshes and that's all that happens. I've checked to be sure that the input information is correct and it is and when the information is incorrect the else statement executes perfectly fine. If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening, please let me know. Thank you.

Here is the segment where the header() statement is made:

```
function validateUser($name, $pass)
{
    $check = verifyUser($name, md5($pass));

    if($check)
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';


        header('location: index.php');


    } else{

        echo'Please enter a correct username and password <br />';
        echo "<a href='http://localhost/cms/admin/login.php'>Try Again?</a>";
        exit;
    }



 }
```

Here is the verifyUser function just in case anyone needs it.

```
   function verifyUser($name, $pass)
   {
// Escape strings
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password' limit 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}

  }
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks. This was from an older tutorial and I'm still in the learning process right now. Do you know about why the header function may not be working?

Comment: Ignore the tutorial, use the PDO one I have linked. As for why it's not working, I'm afraid I'm not going to help you with code using the mysql_* functions. Change to PDO and I'll tell you what's wrong :)

Comment: actually, don't ignore the tutorial -- if you really want to make the world a better place, contact the authors, and ask them to update it.

Comment: Do you have html output before you call `validateUser`?

Comment: @cadavid4j, is page showing any error? Just to only check instead of header, try echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php';"; and see what happens

Comment: Try `exit;`ing after the header, make sure no other code is executed. Also, another note, you should probably be using something stronger than md5, and be salting.

Comment: @cadavid4j, did you start session before using session??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason that `header()` doesn't work is because something else has been output first. `header()` can only be called before anything else has sent output to the browser.

If this is the case, PHP will throw an error when `header()` is called. If you're not displaying errors on the page, you can check your error logs to see if this is happening.

You should also call `die()` or `exit()` immediately after (or a soon as possible after) the `header()` call, to prevent anything else from happening after the redirect header. It's unlikely but possible that something later in the program could also cause the redirect to fail even where the initial `header()` call succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "url" instead of "location":

```
header("refresh:1;url=index.php");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change anything.

Comment: ok, have you tried putting some "echoes" in your code to debug it? For instance: Echo the sql-statement that your verifyUser() function is running, and try copying it and running it manually. Then echo the value of "$check", to see if that returns what you'd expect it to return. This will bring you much more insight into what your code is actually doing (which is not always what you'd expect it to do ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can put this line in your project at very first line (actually before sending any output), otherwise `header` function never will work after sending any output (e.g. html code or echo print etc);

```
ob_start();
```

Or, check that are headers already sent before sending new headers;

```
if(!headers_send()){
   header("header params...");
} else {
   echo "<script>window.location.href="index.php"</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure that `$_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';` is defined

Answer (score -5):

In mysql query use quotes on variable names as follows:

`mysql_query("select * from users where username="'".$username."'" and password="'".$password."'" limit 1");`

Comment: Using quote is a good habit, this will not make any impact on the query. On what basis you're suggesting this solution?